# All subscription posts from on database response

Tags: django

So, I have microblogs system where each blog calls board with a number of simple posts. Any user can create there one board, and subscribes on boards of another users. For manage subscription I create a manytomanyfield membership class. The question is how to get from database all posts of all boards in subscription of a user. My models code :

```
class Board (models.Model):
       title = models.CharField (max_length=30)
       description =  models.CharField (max_length=300)
       author = models.ForeignKey(User)
       created = models.DateTimeField (editable=False)
       subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Subscription")

class  Post (models.Model):
      title = models.CharField (max_length=30)
      description = models.CharField (max_length=320)
      created = models.DateTimeField (editable=False)
      board = models.ForeignKey (Board)

class Subscription (models.Model):
      subcsriber = models.ForeignKey(User)
      board = models.ForeignKey(Board)
      sub_date =  models.DateTimeField (auto_now_add=True)
```

So have I any ability to get list of all sorted posts from all boards in one response. Or I should first get all boards list, then get all posts of each other combine it into one list and then sort it by publication date?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Post.objects.filter(board__subscribers=your_user).order_by('created')
```